# Vercel can't talk to my backend in production

Tags: reactjs, https, dns, vercel

I'm deploying a side-project at the moment that I've built on React+Nodejs.

I deployed the React part using Vercel, what a great service. I then deployed my Node backend to AWS ECS that is currently active and accessible.

The problem is, Vercel configures HTTPS by default so I need to enable HTTPS on my backend as well to allow for communication. Otherwise, I get a "Blocked mixed content" error on the frontend.

I've tried obtaining a certificate from ACM but Vercel has it so that I can't add a CAA record for Amazon (it removes the "." at the end). I currently have a support ticket with Vercel to try and resolve this.

If there's an alternate way to resolve this issue, or if I'm not even on the right track, let me know. Thanks.

Edit: This is the page I followed for ACM: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/setup-caa.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing dot is actually not required. As you can see [here](https://www.whatsmydns.net/#CAA/vercel.com), Vercel is also using multiple CAA record without any issues. You can search for more examples online.

Comment: I believe the dot *is* required for the name field. That website only shows the value field. If it isn't required, then ACM is broken because it consistently fails. Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/setup-caa.html

Comment: You need to use "@" for the root of your domain. The guide should tell you to use "@" or "." as the "name" argument.

Comment: Wow...I deeply appreciate your help, this will help tremendously! Thank you